# A little less after that

Tags: meaning

I encountered this sentence -

> It was an hour's drive to Providence, a little less after that.

What does it mean by "a little less after that"?
Does it mean "after Providence, it will be a little less than an hour to reach the place"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I read too

Comment: Context would make it clearer (the final destination, or at least a general area or a motel say somewhere in the general area beyond Providence, will almost certainly appear in a previous sentence. Which it would have been better to include in the question.)

Comment: I am sorry for not adding that in the original question. The sentence I quoted was a standalone sentence. And from the subsequent sentences it's clear that the destination is not Providence. In the following lines the author described how he reached the destination thoroughly. :)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not very clear in its meaning. The best interpretation without further context is "it will be a little under an hour's drive past Providence" which you have correctly guessed.